# Dialog Box Not Working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
 function showPopup(){
     var popup = $('<div>').dialog();
     popup.html('<div id="mydiv"></div>');
     for (var i=1; i<5; i++)
         setContent($('#mydiv'));
         popup.dialog("option", "buttons", {"Add":function(){
         //code to add 
         $(this).dialog('close');


      $(this).dialog('destroy');},"Cancel":function(){
           //code to add 
           $(this).dialog('close');
           $(this).dialog('destroy');
                                              },    
      });   
      }

      function setContent(container){       
            container.append('<p>sadfsdfsdfsdfdsf</p>');        
      }
```

On clicking a "ADD BUTTON" the showPopup function is called which displays a dialog box setting its content from the setContent method. 
On the first click the content is displayed properly while on further clicks(after the previous dialog is closed) no content is displayed.

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: I would put a hidden div in the page markup to use instead of creating a new one each time like this if this is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 <div class = "mydiv"></div>
```

instead of id = "mydiv"